Getting a good shard key for mongodb for billions of records
At my company we have a mongo collection that has reached 120 million records that is currently sharded. Sadly and painfully, the chosen sharding strategy has been shown to be really bad: suffers both from the scatter/gather pattern and is monotonically increasing, meaning that we experience a terrible hot partition. I have been asked to try and fix this, after a bit of reading and watching resources on mongo sharding, I came to a possible solution, but I am not sure if this would work.
Our data model is something like this:
{
    "containerID": <int>,
    "uniqueID": <string>,
    "creationTimestamp": <timestamp>,
    "freeText": <string>,
    "user": <string>,
    "dataset": <int>
}

Let me give as much as possible information on the current collection:
it has 120 million records;
size is 1 terabyte;
each document has a weight of [2, 200] kb, but I estimate the major part of it being close to 10/20 kb;
containerID and dataset are external keys monotonically increasing;
uniqueID is a random id generated.
About our query patterns, we search with the following use cases:
Using containerID giving a list of values, E.g. [1, 2, 200]. This field represents a relational key into another database that groups our mongodb documents together (somehow a foreign key);
we use a single containerID value sorting by creationTimestamp and paginating. This is the most frequent query in my experience;
We get all the documents querying with dataset (it has a one to many relationship with containerID, so one dataset has multiple containerIDs associated) sorting by creationTimestamp and paginating.
I investigated the containerID field, and I discovered that we have for each key a range of (1, 10.000] values. The average is 200-300 values I think, but it is not a complete even distribution.
My proposed solution would be to add a field in my data model, hashedContainerID that I would populate with my application code that is a hash for my containerID, and use as a shard key {hashedContainerID, creationTimestamp}. In this way, I should avoid the problem of monotonically increasing key (because containerID has been hashed) and enriching the creationTimestamp in the shardKey I should be able to avoid jumbo blocks because further splitting by mongo could still happen for a single containerID.
Does this solution avoid hot partitions while writing documents?
Can this shard key scale up to billions of documents?
Should I add creationTimestamp to the shardkey or am I better off just using hashedContainerID?

What about user? I guess, many queries have this field as query condition which will avoid broadcast queries. It should be a rather stable number of values, thus almost perfect as sharding key.

@WernfriedDomscheit I considered 'user', but it is not very good for two reasons: we have some batch processes that write tons of data that all fall under the same system user (so it would be a real bottleneck) and we never query by user from our platform.
